How to modify a PHP class to accept PgSql\Result as an attribute
I need to find a way (if possible) to make a PHP class accept a PgSql\Result object as an attribute.  PHP 8.1+ has migrated the pgsql result resource to the PgSQL\Result instance.  In prior versions of PHP I could set the attribute like this:
var $results;
....
$this->results = pg_query($conn, "SELECT author, email FROM authors");


But that operation now results in:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: Serialization of 'PgSql\Result' is not allowed in [no active file]

This page goes into detail on the relevant changes that were made in PHP 8.1:
https://php.watch/versions/8.1/PgSQL-resource
Tried declaring the attribute as an PgSQL\Result object but was unsuccessful.  I probably declared it incorrectly.  I'm not particularly proficient in OOP.

EDIT

In simplest terms, this is what I want to work -- if possible:
class foo
{
    var $results; // or whatever needs to replace 'var' to get it to work with a PgSql\Result object

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->results = pg_query($conn, "SELECT author, email FROM authors"); 
    }
}
---------------------
$x = new foo();
$row = pg_fetch_row($x->results);


why using var, and show gettype() of the $results, it must be a string , how can you put object in a string

"a class" accepts  PgSql\Result object as an attribute all right. What your  code shouldn't do is serializing this class' instance (such as storing it in a session). So the error message exactly says.

Hi bhucho, that's my question.  I know I can't put an object in a string, but I used to be able to put the 'pgsql result' resource into the string.  Now that we're dealing with a PgSql\Result object instead, how do I define it as an attribute in my main class definition so that it is available when I instantiate the object?

Hi Your Common Sense, I understand all that. What I need to be able to do is store that PgSql\Result object in my class so that when I instantiate the object I can reference it thusly:
$x = new foo();
$row = pg_fetch_row($x->results);

Did you try to run exactly this  simplest example?

To make it clear: this error message has nothing to do with classes or attributes. There is nothing to "modify" in the class. What has to be changed is how this object is used.

It is a major simplification of the routine in the mammoth application I'm trying to update to PHP 8.3.  What's weird is that if I try to run the simplified code (after adding the connection string, of course) as shown, it works!  No serialization error!  Now I'm officially flummoxed.

Of course there no error. Because there is no serialization in this code. The problem is to find where it happens. From what I was able to Google, it's either saving this object in a session or some multithreading.

Thanks for your research.  It's entirely possible it's being saved in a session variable -- it's a jungle in there.  I'm returning to the fun.  I may be back with updates/questions.

"Serialization of 'PgSql\Result' is not" - where's the code triggering the serialization? And how is this problem directly related to PostgreSQL? Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Running a SELECT query on constructing the class itself looks strange to me anyways - why not gather the data whenever you need it within that class?

Thanks to all who responded.  I discovered that this action is being directly performed on a session object.  If I create a non-session object the code works fine.
As to why the SELECT routine is taking place inside the constructor, all I can think is that the person who created this application wanted to make maintaining the code as difficult as possible.
